# Error of '"_vDSP maxvD", referenced from...' when implementing core-plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-plot, vdsp

I'm trying to implement [this library](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) for creating graphs in my Xcode project. I'm following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-coreplot-project-setup--pre-31791) to insert it in my project. When I finish it and compile and run it, I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link with the Accelerate.framework